# Can this be removed from hold? If not, what else is needed please?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I've reworded the question to be more specific.  If something else is needed, please let me know.

[New DBA, what are some good ways to organize things to be effective? (Scripts, checklists, and common procedures)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/187283)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question you've asked is not a 'bad question', it just isn't a good fit for the Q&A format here on Stack Exchange — note this from the help centre (linked in the close banner on your question):

> if your question … has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format.

There are any number of valid answers to your question and no obvious criteria for choosing which is 'correct', so it isn't the kind of question we want here — maybe try reddit?

Comment: OK, good points.  Thank you.